# RDLC - Objects expand rectangle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I have a RDLC report with a tablix with a rectangle inside that contains another tablix.

[image]

When I print, the smaller tablix expand the width of the rectangle causing the report to be printed in 2 pages for no reason.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this ? I already tried checking "Keep Together" with no success.